# how support different android os?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have some problem.
I have two methods, one called with Api 11 and above,  second method  for old api.

There are settings of my project:

Project Build Target - Google APIs 2.3.3

Manifest file:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

My code:

```
abstract class DoAsyncRequest {
    protected abstract void DoRequest(Connection conn) throws Exception;
}

class DoAsyncRequestLegacy extends DoAsyncRequest {
    protected void DoRequest(Connection conn) throws Exception{
        new FetchTask(conn).execute();// FOR OLD API
    }
}


@TargetApi(11) class DoAsyncRequest_SDK11 extends DoAsyncRequest {
    protected void DoRequest(Connection conn) throws Exception{
        new FetchTask(conn).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);                    //FOR NEW API, but compiller says, that  THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR cannot be resolved or is not a field
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 6):

Usually I test before calling the proper method this way:

```
  // change with the version you want to test
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { 

  } else {

  }
```

Comment: new FetchTask(conn).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);                    //FOR NEW API, but compiller says, that  THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: P.S. I use your code 
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
      req = new DoAsyncRequestLegacy();
     } else {
      req = new DoAsyncRequest_SDK11();
     }

Comment: You should always use the latest version as Build Target. If not, the compiler cqnnot find the new methods.

Comment: @nicopico  i set Project Build Target  to latest version, but now i see error "The project cannot be built until build path errors are  Unknown Java Problem"

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { 

     new FetchTask(conn).execute();// FOR OLD API

  } else {

     new FetchTask(conn).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

  }
```

Comment: Explain more about your problem.

Comment: i have change my code as u give advice .. but i cant able to get response from api .. 
before i have change it i can able to get response from api in lower version

Comment: This code should work as expected. `new FetchTask(conn).execute();` is for OS before Honeycomb. `new FetchTask(conn).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);` this will work on OS Honeycomb and above.